# R.NET could not find function "cor"

Tags: c#, r

I'm using R in a C# webapplication with R.NET. When I add the code below in my webapplication I get following error. But when I run the same code in a console application it works fine. I have no idea why it doesn't work in a webapplication.

Error message:

```
An exception of type 'RDotNet.EvaluationException' occurred in RDotNet.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error: could not find function "cor"
```

Code:

```
    public double Test()
    {
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

        if (engine.IsRunning == false)
        {
            engine.Initialize();
        }

        NumericVector group1 = engine.CreateNumericVector(new double[] { 30.02, 29.99, 30.11, 29.97, 30.01, 29.99 });
        engine.SetSymbol("group1", group1);
        NumericVector group2 = engine.CreateNumericVector(new double[] { 29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98, 30.02, 29.98 });
        engine.SetSymbol("group2", group2);

        var coefficientValue = engine.Evaluate("cor(group1, group2, method = c('pearson'))");
        var coefficientValueNumeric = coefficientValue.AsNumeric();
        double pearsonCoefficient = coefficientValueNumeric.ElementAt(0);
        engine.Dispose();

        return pearsonCoefficient;
    }
```

Comment: The R error sounds like the `stats` package isn't getting loaded.  As far as why this happens only when it's a web app, maybe it's related to the web app running as a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to this problem. Add c:\Program Files\r\R-3.2.0\bin\i386 to the Machine or User's PATH environment variable.

Source: http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/tut_asp_dot_net/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Barry:  use forward slashes ('/') when adapting the PATH variable and restart the server. This worked for me (finally)